# Using resample to align multiple timeseries in pandas

Tags: python, time-series, pandas, resampling

Here's the setup code:

```
import pandas
from datetime import datetime

a_values = [1728, 1635, 1733]
a_index = [datetime(2011, 10, 31), datetime(2012, 1, 31), datetime(2012, 4, 30)]
a = pandas.Series(data=a_values, index=a_index)

aa_values = [6419, 5989, 6006]
aa_index = [datetime(2011, 9, 30), datetime(2011, 12, 31), datetime(2012, 3, 31)]
aa = pandas.Series(data=aa_values, index=aa_index)

apol_values = [1100, 1179, 969]
apol_index = [datetime(2011, 8, 31), datetime(2011, 11, 30), datetime(2012, 2, 29)]
apol = pandas.Series(data=apol_values, index=apol_index)
```

Here's what the data looks like in a table (3rd value for APOL isn't shown):

[image]

The goal is to align the data to calendar quarter markers so the 3 data sets can be compared.  Just glancing at the below dates, Mar 2012, Dec 2011, and Sep 2011 seem like reasonable markers for alignment.

Here's the output with fill_method='ffill':

```
In [6]: a.resample('Q', fill_method='ffill')
Out[6]: 
2011-12-31    1728
2012-03-31    1635
2012-06-30    1733
Freq: Q-DEC

In [7]: aa.resample('Q', fill_method='ffill')
Out[7]: 
2011-09-30    6419
2011-12-31    5989
2012-03-31    6006
Freq: Q-DEC

In [8]: apol.resample('Q', fill_method='ffill')
Out[8]: 
2011-09-30    1100
2011-12-31    1179
2012-03-31     969
Freq: Q-DEC
```

Which looks like this:

[image]

Notice how the most recent numbers in each series don't line up.

And here's the output with fill_method='bfill':

```
In [9]: a.resample('Q', fill_method='bfill')
Out[9]: 
2011-12-31    1635
2012-03-31    1733
2012-06-30     NaN
Freq: Q-DEC

In [10]: aa.resample('Q', fill_method='bfill')
Out[10]: 
2011-09-30    6419
2011-12-31    5989
2012-03-31    6006
Freq: Q-DEC

In [11]: apol.resample('Q', fill_method='bfill')
Out[11]: 
2011-09-30    1179
2011-12-31     969
2012-03-31     NaN
Freq: Q-DEC
```

Which looks like this:

[image]

Again, the most recent numbers in the series don't line up.

Is this the expected output of `resample()` in this scenario?

What can I do to get results where the most recent 3 numbers above are aligned and everything else follows appropriately?

**EDIT**:  Here's what the desired output looks like:

[image]

Comment: can you show us the final output you want, to be sure we understand what you want to achieve.

Comment: just edited the question and added desired final output.  the goal (if  it doesn't go without saying) is to get this programmatically, so adjusting different resample params for each series in some non-automatically detectable way is unfortunately not helpful

Comment: @root, does my desired output make sense?  is there something wrong with the question?  (i see there was a downvote).  thank you very much.

Comment: @ dshap -- added an answer, this should be pretty close. at least you should get the idea how to do it

Comment: Voted to reopen. This is not too localized.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
df1 = DataFrame({'a':a})
df2 = DataFrame({'aa':aa})
df3 = DataFrame({'apol':apol})
df=df1.append([df2,df3]).sort_index()
print df.resample('Q-APR',loffset='-1m').T
```

Output:

```
      2011-09-30  2011-12-31  2012-03-31
a           1728        1635        1733
aa          6419        5989        6006
apol        1100        1179         969
```